# Hosting web services project in Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, jboss, amazon-cloudfront

Hi We have built a java based web services project with using jboss server. How do I host this application with Amazon cloud? This web services act as back end for a mobile android app.

I am looking for PaaS option of Jboss server and Postgres database. I could create a postgres database. But could not find Jboss server.

My understanding is in PaaS, Jboss and Postgres should be able to scale up itself as per demand.

Another option provided by Amazon is EC2 as far as I have understood. But if I go with EC2, I will have install and set up jboss and postgres on my own. Then does it scale up by itself as per demand?

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deploy your web application to AWS and ensure its scalability, you have basically two options:

- EC2 instance [IaaS] - The disadvantage is, as you mentioned in your question, that you have to configure everything manually. Some external mechanism for scaling has to be used. Amazon provides its `AutoScaling` service which can be configured to launch new EC2 instances based on utilization or some other metric.
- Elastic Beanstalk [PaaS] - This service has the auto-scaling already built in and manages the EC2 instances with your application on its own (it takes care about launching them, deploying the app etc). The disadvantage is that JBoss server is not support at the moment (you would have to switch to Tomcat).

There is a way, how to make JBoss work on Elastic Beanstalk, however. ELB has newly added the support for [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) so if you make your JBoss API run in Docker, you can deploy it to ELB and scale it without much effort and configuration.

As for the database, mentioned in your question, Amazon has plenty of choices, Postgres included, in their RDS service.

Comment: Thanks Smajl. But I could work this out. I found that using bitnami, I could initiate jboss server. But I have not understood about what is arrangement between bitnami and amazon. Can you please throw some light on the same?

Comment: Bitnami is a third party product available on the AWS marketplace. You can buy it and run in either as an EC2 instance or on the Elastic Beanstalk.